# Parametrized test is skipped in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Why the following parametrized test get skipped when running with `pytest` from command line? It doesn't happen when running from Intellij IDEA.

```
def list_files(dir):
    return glob.glob(f'{dir}/*.json')

@pytest.mark.parametrize("data_fpath", list_files('../data'))
def test_schema(data_fpath):
```

How can I investigate that and solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a difference, then the current directory is different when running with IntelliJ. Instead of using `../data` relative to current directory, try to make it fixed based on something else (e.g. location of this script).

```
def list_files(dir):
    return glob.glob(f'{dir}/*.json')

THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "data_fpath",
    list_files(os.path.join(THIS_DIR, '..', 'data')))
def test_schema(data_fpath):
    print(data_fpath)
```

Comment: That's one option. But instead of guessing I would like pytest to return reasons for skipping the test. How can I get that information?

Comment: pytest did not officially skipped, it looped over every files (but there are 0 files matching in this directory). If you want it marked as skipped, you could generate the list of files separately `files = list_files(...)`, and then `@pytest.mark.skipif(len(files)==0, reason="no files in this directory")`.